# Как правильно сравнить дату C#

Tags: c#

Ребята подскажите как правильно сравнить дату?
у меня есть запрос в бд, там отбирает строки и возвращает результат, как коллекцию обьекта по шаблону:

```
cmd.ExecObjects(new
        {
            Name = string.Empty,
            Date = DateTime.MinValue,
        });
```

Дальше там идет построение таблицы

```
sb.AppendFormat("Имя:{0}, дата {1} </td><td></td></tr>", row.Name, Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
```

в результате на екране у меня выдает дату 01.01.0001. поэтому нужна доп проверка. Как ее правильно сделать? Как правильно представить дату(сейчас ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Какую дату с чем сравнить? Какая нужна проверка и в чем у вас проблема? Представить дату? Определитесь уже с вопросом... PS: DateTime.MinValue это и есть 01.01.0001

Comment: Какая нужна проверка? Чего с чем? Уточните вопрос.

Comment: в бд должна быть дата. например 19.01.18 . если ее нету, то выдаст  01.01.0001 . что не совсем правильно) вот и думаю, как это все правильно сделать

Comment: @Nastya обычно используются "nullable" типы. Они закладываются изначально при проектировании базы/процедур. в этом случае модель данных отображает их в виде "DateTime?". Можно так же уточнить тип желаемых данных непосредственно при запросе. 
Получая такой тип всегда можно узнать содержит ли поле значение или null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот как я реализовывал нахождение разницы во времени через DateTime

> dataInfo- объект полученный из БД

В нем `dataInfo.Time` - время в формате "dd.MM.yyyy hh:MM:ss:mm"

```
 DateTime enteredDate = DateTime.Parse(dataInfo.Time);
                var x = DateTime.Now;
                var time = (enteredDate - x).Duration();
```

а уже из `time` конкретно что нужно: годы, месяца, дни, часы.....

Answer (score 2):

> Как правильно представить дату(сейчас ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")?

```
string text = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

или добавив одинарные кавычки побоказ слэшей:

```
string text = dateTime.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.fff");
```

- MM - Месяц с предшествующим нулем
- M - просто месяц без нулей
- dd - с ну нулем
- d - без нулей
- yyyy - 4-символьный год
- yy - 2-хсимвольный год
- HH - 24часовый формат часов с предшествующим нулем
- H - 24часовый формат без предшествующим нуля
- hh - 12часовый формат часов с предшествующим нулем
- h - 12часовый формат часов без нуля
- mm - минут с предшествующим нулем
- m - без нуля
- ss - секунды с предшествующим нулем
- s - секунды без предшествующего нуля.

---

А на тему сравнения....

Т.к. обьект ДатыВремени хранит и дату и время, а нужно сравнивать только даты... То нужно вытягивать именно дату из DateTime :

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);

if( dt1.Date == dt2.Date)//смотри, я работаю только с датами!
{
    //some action
}
```